# List of ValueObjects a valid thing?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, value-object

Let's say we have an entity **Customer** which can have multiple email addresses.
We create a ValueObject "**EmailAddress**", upon creation it checks if the address is valid.

Is this concept valid and does it make sense?

```
public class Customer : IAggregateRoot
{
    public List<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses = new();
}
```

If so, can this ValueObject also hold a "Remark" for a given email address? And how to update the ValueObject?

Comment: What version of what language is this? I've never seen `new()` used that way before.

Comment: @candied_orange I believe that’s C# 9 Type Inference

Comment: @candied_orange Like Rik D said, it's a C# 9 thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ValueObject can certainly contain more than one property. And it’s perfectly fine to put such ValueObjects in a collection.

How do you update such a ValueObject? You don’t! You replace them. ValueObjects are immutable, so they can never change.

Does it make sense to combine an email address with a note in a ValueObject? It doesn’t. ValueObjects are equal if all of their properties are equal. That means that (a@b.com, remark1) is not the same as (a@b.com, remark2). Duplicate email addresses with different notes is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Cleared up a lot - Valid point that it doesn't make sense. Since I never really used value objects before I started looking into DDD it's quite new. How would one use the EmailAddress valueobject on an Entity which can hold a remark/note for a given Customer? Sidenote: I would like to reuse the functionality for other entities.

Comment: @Jesse A value object is simply an object that you're interested in because of the value of its properties (as opposed to some extraneous identity, like an ID, or a reference as in `object.ReferenceEquals()`). There's nothing novel or unusual about them. You *have* used value objects before - int, float, bool, DateTime - these are all value objects. Two ints, or two DateTimes, are equal if they have the same value, doesn't matter where they came from; it's the same idea here.

Comment: @Jesse That's really all there is to it, everything else is a matter of implementation; DDD itself doesn't require special interfaces or base classes for aggregate roots and value objects. Email + remark doesn't make conceptual sense within EmailAddress because you likely want to be able to *compare addresses*, but it may make sense in something like EmailInfo, which can be a composite of (EmailAddress + remark (string)). Values can be nested. Now depending on what you intend to do with it, you can choose to treat EmailInfo as a value object, or not.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Thank You! Sounds clear!

Comment: If you do decide to add a remark field there is a way to keep it from sticking you with duplicate emails: override Equals(). Will probably want to override GetHashCode() while you’re at it.

Comment: @candied_orange I was wondering about that, is it generally acceptable to override the Equals to only check for the EmailAddress to be the same?  Then I can add the remark field - but feels a bit like cheating?

Comment: It's largest drawback is that it’s non-obvious. You’d be making me look inside your class to understand. Make sure you have a real good reason to do that. I hate code that makes me look inside and forces me to remember what I found there with no hints. But it’s a well known trick. Learn it well. Use it when you can’t do better.

Comment: I should also note: the more modern language versions also let you pass in a lambda that controls comparisons. I find that trick more readable.

Comment: @Jesse It would indeed be confusing to override Equals in that way. It seems that there's an implicit business rule here that a customer cannot have duplicate email addresses with different remarks, so I'd make it the job of the `Customer` entity to enforce that.

Comment: @casablanca Indeed, that's the requirement. However I could also just make it an entity below the Custom aggregate root. I'm not sure what the best way would be to deal with this. Since we might add more bools to the emailadres to check if it can be used in certain messages for example.